# Proving $x \in \mathrm{int}(S \cap T)$ implies that $x \in \mathrm{int}(S) \cap \mathrm{int}(T)$

Tags: real-analysis

**Proposition** If $x \in \mathrm{int}(S \cap T)$, then $x \in \mathrm{int}(S) \cap \mathrm{int}(T)$, where $\mathrm{int}(S)$ is the set of interior points of the set $S$.

I have proven this proposition by demonstrating that $\mathrm{int}(S \cap T) \subseteq \mathrm{int}(S) \cap \mathrm{int}(T)$, which is the typical, formal way in proving that one set is a subset of another.

Instead, could we just articulate the meaning of the symbols?

**Proof**

Since $x \in \mathrm{int}(S \cap T)$, then $x$ is an interior point of $S \cap T$, which is to say that $x$ is an interior point of $S$ and $T$. But this is precisely the same statement as $x \in \mathrm{int}(S) \cap \mathrm{int}(T)$. Hence, $\mathrm{int}(S \cap T) \subseteq \mathrm{int}(S) \cap \mathrm{int}(T)$.

$\blacksquare$

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite understand your second argument. Can you write it differently? It sounds like you are saying that if $x$ is an interior point of $S\cap T$ then $x$ is an interior point of $S$, and an interior point of $T$ - but this is exactly what you are trying to prove.

Comment: What I mean is that I have proven the proposition in the "rigorous" manner, which is to show that $\mathrm{int}(S\cap T) \subseteq \mathrm{int}(S) \cap \mathrm{int}(T)$. But I was wondering if we could bypass the formal proof that I have just outlined, and instead use "wordplay," like I have done in the above post to which I raise my question. But I'll rewrite the post to hopefully better articulate my question.

Comment: "then x is an interior point of S∩T, which is to say that x is an interior point of S and T".  Why should that be true.?  That's precisely the statement you are trying to prove.

Comment: @fleablood So $x \in \mathrm{int}(S \cap T)$ is not the same as saying that $x$ is an interior point of $S$ and an interior point $T$? It seems to be true in virtue of the meaning of the word's employed, specifically $\mathrm{int}(S \cap T)$ and $S \cap T$.

Comment: No, it is the same but you can't accept that it is true without somehow demonstrating it.

Comment: Fleablood's point is that if we say "...then x is an *oliphant* point of $S\cap T$, which is to say that x is an *oliphant* point of $S$ and an *oliphant* point of $T$," then we actually need to cite a definition for "*oliphant* point" and a reason why this might be so. A proof must not assume that what may seem obvious to you, is obvious to everyone.

Comment: If that were a given then the there is no point in the exercise at all as it'd just be a given.  Basically you are saying "It's true because it is true and is that a proof?"  No.  It isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any arbitrary point which is interior to the intersection of $S\cap T$ must also a point interior to a set which contains $S\cap T$ (a supraset). (Why?--*refer to what "interior point" means here*--)     Both $S$ and $T$ are suprasets to their intersection $(S\supseteq S\cap T), (T\supseteq S\cap T)$.   Thus $$\forall x: \Big(x\in\operatorname{int}(S\cap T) \implies x\in \operatorname{int}(S) \wedge x\in \operatorname{int}(T)\Big)\\ \operatorname{int}(S\cap T)\subseteq \operatorname{int}(S)\cap \operatorname{int}(T)$$

Argue for the converse.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just claim being an interior point of the intersection is the same as being in the intersection of the interior points without some justification.

However the justification is simple.  If $x \in \text{int}(S \cap T) \implies$ there is an open ball $B$ around x such that $B \subset  S \cap T$.  As $ S \cap T \subset S$ and $ S \cap T \subset T$ we can say $B \subset S \cap T \subset S$ and $B \subset S \cap T \subset T$.  *NOW* you can point out the x is an interior point of T and an interior point of S.  So $x \in \text{int}(S) \cap \text{int}(T)$.

Answer (score 0):

Without the definition of interior points, no proof.

Since you already did one side of the proof, here is the converse: if x ∈ int(S) ∩ int(T), then x ∈ int(S ∩ T).

x ∈ int(S) ⊂ S, and x ∈ int(T) ⊂ T, so x ∈ S ∩ T. And the intersection of a finite number of open sets is open, too, so int(S) ∩ int(T) is open, and x is an interior point of it. Thus, x is an interior point of S ∩ T.

Final result: int(S) ∩ int(T) = int(S ∩ T).

Answer (score 0):

If a point $x$ is not in a set $S$ then we will say $x$ is a non-point of $S$, and we will write $\mathrm{non}(S)$ for the set of non-points of $S$.

I claim that $\mathrm{non}(S \cap T) \subseteq \mathrm{non}(S) \cap \mathrm{int}(T)$.

**"Proof"**

Since $x \in \mathrm{non}(S \cap T)$, then $x$ is a non-point of $S \cap T$, which is to say that $x$ is a non-point of $S$ and $T$. But this is precisely the same statement as $x \in \mathrm{non}(S) \cap \mathrm{non}(T)$. Hence, $\mathrm{non}(S \cap T) \subseteq \mathrm{non}(S) \cap \mathrm{int}(T)$.

Comment: Well, it's not *that* bad.  There is a condition of the definition of interior point that to be an interior point of a set a neighborhood must exist entirely in the set.  If a set exists in an intersection of sets it exists in each of the sets as well.  However, one does actually have to *state* this argument and point out that this *is* part of the definition.

Comment: @fleablood When trying to see why a proof of a true statement is invalid, I think it's helpful to look at a similar proof of an obviously false statement. I believe the question being asked is essentially "Doesn't $x \sim S \cap T$ mean the same thing as $x \sim S$ and $x \sim T$?"

Comment: I agree entirely, and I think it's not enough to say say "well it's clear" as I pointed out in the comments.  Bennedict basically scoffed and thought it was implicit in the definitions of intersection and interior.  And in a sense he is right.  Unlike an oliphant point or a non-point or hinklehufferdunk point an interior point's definition implies it and a neighbor are within a set.  And if they are in a set they are within all suprasets.  So the definition *does* imply it.  I don't the Benedict is actually ... to be continued....

Comment: ... continued ... is actually confusing $x \sim S \cap T$ with $x \sim S$ and $s \sim T$ and I don't think he'd make the same mistake with a hinklehufferdunk point.  But *my* point is even if something is "implicit" you still have to point out that it is so.  If it were *that* implicit we wouldn't have been asked to prove it in the first place.  I think among experience mathematicians it's okay to say "it's implicit as neghborhoods in the intersection of sets are in each individual sets".  This is, after all, why why state without blinking eye things like ... to be continued....

Comment: ....  $A \cap B \subset A$ because it is implicit.  Before we can state $A \cap B \subset A$ we *do* have to prove it.  Just once.  But it has to be done.  The same it true of this argument about the interior of an intersection is the intersection of interiors.  It's got a nice word play cadence and it's clear if you really think about it, but you can't just say "it's implicit" without explaining why.